# NameError: name 'quit' is not defined for pygame

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

I tried to make a little snake game (with pygame) and I tried to export it as a .exe with cx_Freeze. The game works fine, until I close the window. When I do that, there is this Error message:

[image: Error message]

But I just used it to close the game loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            Game()
```

If I open the .py file I don't get any Error message. I don't have any Idea how I possibly could fix this problem.

My setup.py:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("snake.py", base="Win32GUI", icon="links/icon.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Snake",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages": ["pygame"], "include_files": ["links/"]}},
    executables=executables
    )
```

And here is my Code: [Codeshare.io](https://codeshare.io/5Z6YrX)

Comment: Don't post a link to your code. (Codeshare.io doesn't seem to be up atm). Post the relevant code that calls `quit()`.

Comment: You are calling the function `quit()` under `pygame.quit()` at line 42 on the codepen that is not defined in your program. Create the function or remove the line.

Comment: `quit` always fails for me too when freezing. Use `sys.exit()` instead

Comment: quit() is already a defined function, pygame.quit() too. If I delete one of them it will only generate more errors or bugs...

Comment: Do you have a `while` loop running up before the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes this for loop is located in a while loop

Comment: in python the quit()  function is only available if the code is imported as a module exit() would be better

Answer (score 2):

So I solved the problem by typing `sys.exit()` instead of typing `quit()`
I tried this before but I didn't know that I had to `import sys`.

*(Sorry I'm a beginner)*